# OpenDKIM's UNIX socket and permissions for "others"

Tags: socket, opendkim

Postfix installation procedure created a system user `postfix` and it's primary group `postfix` while installation procedure for OpenDKIM created a system user `opendkim` and it's primary group `opendkim`.

To enable Postfix and OpenDKIM to work together most of the administrators do two things:

### A

They append a secondary group `opendkim` to Postfix.

### B

They set OpenDKIM configuration file `/etc/opendkim.conf` to create a UNIX socket using these three (two) lines:

```
UMask                   002
PidFile                 /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid
Socket                  local:/var/spool/postfix/opendkim/opendkim.sock
```

Official OpenDKIM documentation states this for the configuration parameter `UMask`:

> Requests a specific permissions mask to be used for file creation.
> This only really applies to creation of the socket when Socket
> specifies a UNIX domain socket, and to the PidFile (if any);

I know that UNIX sockets are convenient because they can limit user privileges. In my case I want OpenDKIM to work with Postfix as safe as possible. But with `UMask` set to `002` UNIX socket will be created with ownership `opendkim:opendkim` and privileges `664` = `rw-rw-r--`.

I understand that group members (Postfix) need to read and write to the UNIX socket, but I don't understand why almost all tutorials online ([A](https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/setting-up-dkim-and-spf), [B](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-dkim-with-postfix-on-debian-wheezy), [C](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/configure-spf-and-dkim-in-postfix-on-debian-9/)...) leave read permissions for others?

Is this a general missconception? Wouldn't a reasonable value for `UMask` be `007`? Also the PID file is created using the same privileges...

If I check any other UNIX socket on my system some also have rights for others... Why is that important to have?

```
┌───┐
│ # │ root > mailer > ~
└─┬─┘
  └─> ss -x -l | head -n 10
Netid State  Recv-Q Send-Q                               Local Address:Port                                   Peer Address:Port                                 
u_dgr UNCONN 0      0                              /run/systemd/notify 14848                                             * 0                                    
u_str LISTEN 0      128               /var/run/dovecot/director-userdb 13957121                                          * 0                                    
u_str LISTEN 0      128                           /run/systemd/private 14852                                             * 0                                    
u_str LISTEN 0      100                          /var/run/dovecot/dict 13957125                                          * 0                                    
u_str LISTEN 0      128                    /var/run/dovecot/dict-async 13957129                                          * 0                                    
u_str LISTEN 0      1                      /var/run/irqbalance568.sock 17673                                             * 0                                    
u_dgr UNCONN 0      0                      /run/systemd/journal/syslog 14859                                             * 0                                    
u_str LISTEN 0      128                        /var/run/dovecot/config 13957133                                          * 0                                    
u_str LISTEN 0      128                   /var/run/dovecot/login/login 13957135                                          * 0                                    

┌───┐
│ # │ root > mailer > ~
└─┬─┘
  └─> ls -l /var/run/dovecot/config 
srw------- 1 root root 0 Dec 31 07:35 /var/run/dovecot/config

┌───┐
│ # │ root > mailer > ~
└─┬─┘
  └─> ls -l /var/run/dovecot/login/login 
srw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 Dec 31 07:35 /var/run/dovecot/login/login
```

Comment: In Debian, the default opendkim.conf sets umask to `007` (the [wiki page](https://wiki.debian.org/opendkim) also discusses setting up the socket).

Answer (score 1):

Using a umask of `002` likely is influenced by the common default umask of `022` - which is also what the opendkim sample configuration [cites](https://github.com/trusteddomainproject/OpenDKIM/blob/551ab3820476234def82eb2223ca6c7b45b45076/opendkim/opendkim.conf.sample#L761).

Since opendkim uses one umask setting for both the pidfile *and* the socket file, there might be the need to allow read access on the pidfile for other such that also the socket file gets created with read permission for other, as a *side effect*.

If you don't even enable pidfile creation (e.g. with systemd you don't need it) and you add the postfix user to the opendkim group then a umask of `007` makes sense.

---

Alternatively, you can let create opendkim the socket in a directory that is only accessible by opendkim and postfix like this:

```
$ cat /etc/tmpfiles.d/opendkim.conf 
d /run/opendkim-postfix 0750 opendkim postfix -
```

opendkim main config snippet:

```
UMask   000
Socket local:/run/opendkim-postfix/opendkim.sock
```

Which results in:

```
# find /run/opendkim-postfix -printf '%M %m %p\n'
drwxr-x--- 750 /run/opendkim-postfix
srwxrwxrwx 777 /run/opendkim-postfix/opendkim.sock
```

That way you don't have to add the postfix user to the opendkim group.

---

The quality of the tutorials you cite might be limited, because some cloud providers outsource their technical documentation to customers who are then incentivized by cloud credits. Thus, as one can imagine, such a tutorial may use other existing tutorials and sample configurations without much critique.